# Does nested objects takes much performance to be projected, filtered and sorted?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a `database` with 50 million documents and each document has a `object` field which has dozens of other nested objects within. Basically this field is a `XML` file converted to an `object`. I was making some tests with `aggregate()` and `find()` but I noticed that projecting and filtering this field takes much performance loss.
For example

```
$cursor = $db->find(array(
            'id_empresa' => 7,
            'tipo_doc' => 'nfe',
            'xml.NFe.infNFe.emit.xNome' => ['$regex' => 'auto', '$options' => 'i'],
            '$and' => array(['$or' => array(
                        ['xml.NFe.infNFe.emit.xNome' => ['$regex' => 'me', '$options' => 'i']],
                        ['xml.NFe.infNFe.dest.xNome' => ['$regex' => 'me', '$options' => 'i']],
                        ['xml.NFe.infNFe.transp.transporta.xNome' => ['$regex' => 'me', '$options' => 'i']]
                    )])
                ), array(
            'limit' => 100,
            'sort' => ['xml.NFe.infNFe.emit.xNome' => 1],
            'projection' => array(
                'id_empresa' => 1,
                'tipo_doc' => 1,
                '_id' => 1,
                'xml.NFe.infNFe.emit.xNome' => 1,
                'xml.NFe.infNFe.ide.nNF' => 1,
                'xml.NFe.infNFe.dest.xNome' => 1,
                'xml.NFe.infNFe.transp.transporta.xNome' => 1,
            )
        ));
```

In this example there is only 4 projected fields of this object but in most cases it will be around 20~40 fields.

Is there any way to get better performance when working with those nested objects?